# undefined offset 1 PHP error

Tags: php

I am receiving the following error in PHP:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 1  on line 552 in file
>   includes/classes/ia.core.smarty.php

Here is the PHP code that causes it:

```
} else { // this scheme used by plugins
            list($path, $file) = explode('|', $params['file']);
            $type = !isset($params['type']) ? 'thumbnail' : $params['type'];

            $url = $iaCore->iaView->assetsUrl . 'uploads/' . $path . $type . '/' . $file;
        }
```

What does the error mean? On pages i get this error thumbnails are not displayed. Thanks

Comment: offset in your case is "file" and "type"

Comment: i think problem isn't here, problem is there where from you are calling this class . Check what type of arguments are you sending to this class.

Comment: this line is probably causing error `$url = $iaCore->iaView->assetsUrl . 'uploads/' . $path . $type . '/' . $file;` try to `print_r($url);` and you will see what it will return

Comment: The only place offset 1 is used is in the list($path, $file)... line. IMO the error can only mean that the exploded array doesn't have an index > 0. Ergo $params['file'] doesn't contain any pipes (|).